# Error when installing SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008, installation

When installing SQL Server 2008 on a Windows 7 machine, it experiences the following error.

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup
>   ------------------------------   The following error has occurred:
>
> Attempted to perform an unauthorized
>   operation.
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed
>   action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel
>   this action and continue setup.
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22&EvtType=0xE32A4906%25400x08A3AE96

Any suggestions on what this **unauthorized operation** might be?

Comment: Are you running it as an administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Are you installing SQL Server Enterprise? Only the SQL Server 2008 Standard and Express editions can be installed on Windows 7.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx

Comment: thats a good thing to know.